# Is there any free RTMP library for Objective-C?

Tags: gratis, osx, video, library, streaming

I'm looking for a free client RTMP library for Objective-C.

I'm trying to stream video picked up from AVFoundation framework.

The only thing I found is : http://ios-rtmp-library.com/.

But it's way too expensive.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and state what exactly your requirements are (must-haves and nice-to-haves)? For a guide what might be expected, please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)